# What is required for a British citizen to return to the UK with Indonesian spouse and children?

Tags: immigration, family, uk-citizens

What are the rules? My son is living in Bali with his Indonesian wife of almost 9 years. Within the next year or two, he is hoping to move back to the UK with his wife and children and settle here. What are the stipulation?

Comment: Are his children British citizens? If so, they'll only need to worry about a visa for his wife.

Comment: @Dorothy Downie Assuming only his wife needs a visa, information is available here https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa